# What does R_CURSOR mean in DB_File?

Tags: perl, berkeley-db

I've been trying to replace BerkeleyDB module in some old Perl with DB_File ties. Reading the DB_File documentation on CPAN is helpful, but not complete. It mentions some flags to use for put, tie, etc and I'm not sure what they mean. `R_CURSOR` is one of those.

Specifically, if I use `put` with `R_CURSOR`, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `man dbopen` for the C level API which describes these flags, as `DB_file` is really a very thin wrapper around that.

The meaning of this flag differs according to which method you use it on, when used with `put` this means that a value is replaced (rather than added before or after) and needs to be used after an existing search, i.e., after using the `seq` function at the C level.

Comment: I'll have to use `man dbopen` at the google prompt since I'm on a windows box ;)

Comment: I used Google on that too. Scrolling is a little easier anyway